# Function Question: Where does the $3$ come from?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone explain me how did ''3'' appear here ?

[image]

Comment: 2x + x = 3x. Then you divide the 3 out to get x.

Comment: so the X is the same as 1 in this one ?

Comment: If $x=y$ then  $\frac{x}{z}=\frac{y}{z}$.  In this case, $3x=-6$ so $\frac{3x}{3}=\frac{-6}{3}$

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, really helped me :)

Comment: 2x + x is like 2 apples plus another apple.  That's a total of 3 apples.

Comment: $1$ is called the multiplicative identity. e.g. $x=1\cdot x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal is to isolate $x$ on one side.  This is called "solving for $x$."

You can add or subtract the same quantity -- any quantity -- from both sides, and the equation still holds.  (If it was equal before you did that, it will be equal after.)  In the first step, you're adding $x$ to both sides, and subtracting $4$ from both sides.

You can simplify expressions (like $2x+x$ becomes $3x$ and $-2-4$ becomes $-6$ in the next step).

You can multiply or divide both sides by the same quantity -- any quantity except $0$ -- and the equation will still hold.  That's where the $3$ comes into play.  It's the final step to isolating $x$.